# Impulse in vertical circular motion

Tags: classical-mechanics

I'd really appreciate some help on starting a problem to do with vertical circular motion. I think once I know how to start I can work out the rest, but I honestly have no idea how to even attempt this.

Given a resting pendulum of length s with a particle of mass m, if it is hit with an impulse I, how do I find how the angle the string makes with the vertical when the particle first comes to rest?

Thanks a lot